# If $T\in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n)$ invertible, why are there orthogonale matrices $P,Q$ s.t. $T=PDQ$ withe $D$ diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T\in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n)$ invertible. Why are there matrices $P,Q\in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n)$ orthogonal s.t. $$T=PDQ$$
with $D=diag[t_1,...,t_n]$ diagonale and $|\det T|=t_1...t_n$ ?

I was thinking about spectral theorem, but here $T$ is not symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Use spectral theorem on the symmetric matrix $T^tT$. Moreover, since $T^tT>0$ (why ?), if $S$ is orthogonal s.t. $$S^tT^tTS=\tilde D$$
with $\tilde D$ diagonal, you can write $\tilde D$ as $$\tilde D=D^2,$$
where $ D=diag(t_1,\cdots, t_n)$, and $t_i>0$. In particular,
$$D^{-1}S^tT^tTSD^{-1}=I,$$
and thus $$P:=TSD^{-1},$$
orthogonal. Therefore $$T=PDS^{-1},$$
and setting $Q=S^{-1}$, the claim follow.